# How to pass a value of type Date in a Spring Boot Rest Call?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, postman

I have a class Model Object class as @RequestBody to a RestController in Spring Boot

```
@Data
class User {
      private String name;
      private Date dob;
 }
```

I am calling this API from postman with the following JSON body

```
{
 "name" : "Michael",
 "dob" : "13/09/19"
 }
```

I get a status 200 OK with this message

'Error occurred while parsing body. Please try with the correct payload.'

My data is not getting submitted. I know the problem is with date, how do I send the proper date?

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to annotate the dob field like this:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yy")
private Date dob;
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates